# How can I automatically export Fusion Widgets as image?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, fusioncharts

I am using Fusion Charts Suite in my application and I am facing problem while automatically exporting Fusion Widgets and Fusion Maps as image. It is achievable using right click option, but I want it to be done automatically like in the case with Fusion Charts.

I have tried multiple solutions but failed to accomplish this.

Kindly help me with this if anyone knows how to do it.

Thanks and Regards,
Rahul Ranjan

Answer (score 0):

What API are using to automate this?

Try calling the `mapObject.exportMap()`.

[edit]

I find another work-around: try `mapObject.ref.exportChart()` function.